# Repeatably generate a read error for testing?

Tags: files, pipe, io, testing, error-handling

I'm trying to test the error handling in some software, in particular what happens when an error occurs reading from a file or pipe.  Is there a simple way to send a certain amount of data to stdout and then generate an I/O error?  (I.e., the process doing the reading would see read(2) return -1.)  A simple shell recipe would be great, but I don't mind writing code if that's the only way.

Comment: You probably don't mean "read(2) return -1" because that is pretty normal but "errno == EIO".