# How to detach a disk in Linux (simulate a crash of partition/disk)?

Tags: centos, mount, virtualbox, hard-disk, unmounting

For testing purpose I need to simulate a crash of the disk (by detaching it) while other processes are using it.
I tried:

```
umount -f /srv/node/d1/
```

It doesn't want to unmount it. It shows me the next message:

```
umount: /srv/node/d1: target is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

There several processes which I don't want to stop manually because it will not be a crash. Does somebody know how to just detach a disk in linux? It would be more easy to detach it physically but I am using a virtual machine with virtual disks.

Comment: may be `echo "1" >/sys/dev/block/<id>/device/delete` , where `<id>` is the id of a block device?

Comment: You can simulate failures of disks using `scsi_debug` kernel module. Or do you need to test one of your existing real devices?

Comment: @rudimeier I need to simulate it with the existing device

Comment: If this is a virtuel machine you can "unpresent" the disk. (not sure that will properly simulate a crash)

Comment: @Archemar Do you know how to do it?

Comment: It depend on virtualization system, in vmware properties -> disk -> remove

Comment: I am using VirtualBox... It doesn't allow any changes when a VM is running.

Comment: `umount -l` will leave it mounted for processes that already have it open, but unmount it for all others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to use device mapper doing a linear remapping to the underlying disk and mounting from there as you can then simulate the disk crashing by switching device mapper to return the error target (e.g. through the use of `dmsetup wipe_table`). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144200/134856 for this and other (such as using `scsi_debug`) disk error simulation techniques.